# How can i view all the commits of a branch on GitHub?

Tags: github

In GitHub, how can I get a list of commits on a branch?

When i open the webpage for a repository, i click the "branches" tab among "commits", "releases" and "contributor" tabs. Then i click the branch in interest, but I don't see a list of commits on the webpage of the branch.

If there is a pull request for merging the branch into another branch, when I open the webpage for the pull request, I see the "Commits" tab among "Conversations" and "Files Changed" tabs. Clicking "Commits" tab will show me a list of commits on the branch.

So GitHub seems to organize the commits on pull request level, rather than on branch level. Is it correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

When you have opened the branch you want in GitHub's code tab, click on `[number] commits` and you'll see the full commit history starting from that branch. Note that there will be overlap between branches that are based on each other because unlike a pull request, this is a full history view instead of a comparison.

Comment: Thanks. click on [number] commits will show all the commits on all the branches in the repository, not just the commits on the particular branch. Can I list all the commits of the branch only?

Comment: Git branches are simply pointers to commits that move over time. Because of this, all those older overlapping commits actually are "on" the branch, they're still children of the newer unique commits.

To compare new commits that are introduced in a branch that are not in the parent branch (similarly to a pull request), visit the branch in GitHub and click `New pull request` next to the branch switcher. Don't worry, this won't actually create a new pull request without confirmation, it's just GitHub's old compare button renamed.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this answer. I'd gotten used to GitLab and had forgotten how confusing and annoying it can be to find certain basic info on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

There’s now [Activity](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/viewing-activity-and-data-for-your-repository/using-the-activity-view-to-see-changes-to-a-repository) on the repo home page, from where you can filter commits by branch, user or time.

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/activity
```

Answer (score 0):

On main page of repo find commits word on link, and click, or use link `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/commits/<branch>`